# PHP Abstract class return type of child class

Tags: php, inheritance, abstract

How can an abstract class in PHP return the type of the child extending it?

```
abstract class MyAbstractClass {
    public static function fromID($id) : returnType { <======
        ...
    }
}

class MyChildClass extends MyAbstractClass {
    public function specificFunctionToThisClass(){
         ...
    }
    
}

$item = new MyChildClass()->fromID(3);
$item->specificFunctionToThisClass();
```

The example above is over simplified.

Right now if i call the method *fromID(var)* in any of the child classes they will return an object of type *MyAbstractClass*. How can i define the return type of that function in the *MyAbstractClass* so that no mather what child calls that method it will return the child's class instead of the parent one.

FYI I know i could implement the same function in every children and redirecting the call to the parent but specifying a more specific return type. Long story short my child class are more than 100 and it would be a lot easier defining it only on the parent so that any future changes to the code would not need to be done on every single child class

Comment: Any child _is_ automatically also of the parent class. That's how inheritence works basically. And since you cannot instantiate an abstract class, the object must always be a derived child. Type of an object will _always_ be of the concrete class you have instantiated. Parent classes don't know of their children. If you need specialized (typed) objects, you'd have to use factories (one factory per concrete class).

Comment: I know that at runtime the object will be of the correct type but having that return type specified helps getting autocomplete and errors gone in the IDE cause the IDE doenst know it

Answer (score 1):

That `returnType` should be `MyAbstractClass`, without any implementation (child implements).

This might not be possible, but the child can return an instance of it's own. For dynamic configuration the `$model` can have configurations specific to the parent - and the child.

Make everything abstract, with `abstract class` and `abstract static function`:

```
abstract class Model {
    abstract static function fromArray( array $model ): Model;
    abstract static function fromID( int $id ): Model;
}

class LightSettings extends Model {
    public function __construct( array|null $config ) {
        parent::__construct( $config );
    }
    static function fromArray( array $model ): LightSettings {
        return new LightSettings( $model );
    } 
    static function fromID( int $$preset_id ): LightSettings {
        return new LightSettings( null )->load( $preset_id );
    }
    ...
}
```

The constructor obviously could as well take `int $$preset_id`, but it's flexible.

Comment: The function is implemented in the parent class because the code is the same for every child that implements that class, implementing it in every child would defeat the purpose of using and abstract parent class in the first place

Comment: In your example your abstract class is just the same as an interface, not the purpose of my question sorry

Answer (score 0):

Intended this to be a comment but it is too long for a comment.

Building on Martin Zeitler's answer (sorry Martin, I'm copying your code here below) with an extra static method in the Model class:

```
abstract class Model {
    abstract static function fromArray( array $model ): Model;
    abstract static function fromID( int $id ): Model;

    // Common stuff for the fromArray factory
    protected static function populateFromArray(Model $model, array $modelArray): Model {
    // Do whatever is common here
    return $model;
}

class LightSettings extends Model {
    static function fromArray( array $model ): LightSettings {
        return parent::populateFromArray(new LightSettings(), $model);
    }
enter code here
    static function fromID( int $$preset_id ): LightSettings {
        // Similar implementation as in fromArray()
    }
    ...
}
```

Comment: Guys, you keep giving the same answer over and over xD; Per my question: I know there's a way to do it implementing methods in the children. I told as much as that in my FYI section of my question xD i'm asking if there's a way to do it using any kind of php reserved accessors that could help me "only" code on the parent; we're talking roughly 9000 lines of codes in the parent, if i have to do copy and paste it mora than 100 times over, i might as well not use a parent class in the first place...

but thanks for trying anyway ahah

Comment: And BTW with the amount of REP you have i wouldn't be so quick on judging other people, i came here asking for help, no one's making you answer my question and i'm sure you have better things to do with your day, but again, i've been wrong before ;)

Comment: I'm criticising the way the code you're working on is structured, whether you or someone else wrote that is irrelevant. Trust me, I've done things badly in the past but I've learned better ways of doing things and my intention was only to point out that the system is more than likely getting to an unsustainable state, if it isn't already. If you choose to take that as a personal attack on you then there's nothing I can do about that.

Comment: Entreprise platforms are not your typical hello world 10 liner. The code is long cause it needs to be - simple as that and really completly besides the point in the context of my question. As for it getting to any sort of unsustainable state, chill, it's not; As for your last comment, i'm not taking as a personal attack i'm simply stating the obvious: You're making assumptions without any prior knowledge of core context; you assumed it to be bad code without asking more insights which i would have given. I understand people code differently but without context you can't really assume anything

Answer (score 0):

Ok, your question was:

> How can an abstract class in PHP return the type of the child extending it?

respectively

> How can i define the return type of that function in the
> MyAbstractClass so that no mather what child calls that method it will
> return the child's class instead of the parent one.

Short answer is: you can't

Inheritance works top to bottom... under no circumstance can a parent class know it's children.

Imagine a framework. Classes from the framework are intended to be derived. But not the author of the framework writes the inherited class, but some developer who has downloaded that framework and uses it in his/her project. And there can thousands of developers who have done the same, but with different child classes. How would the author of the framework would know all the derived classes? He can't, right?

Comment: You are assuming the parent class will have to know the child class to achieve this but that's not the case. The function will be called on the child class and it will know what class it actually is.

Answer (score 0):

I suppose this could be achieved by utilizing the `static` keyword. Not as in a static variable bu like the alternative of `self`, meaning the class of the instance this method is being called on. For some reason PHP thinks it's not a problem to give two different things the same name.

Anyway, the defined return type does not temper with the return value. It simply checks if the return value matches the type we want.

So the answer is to create the object with the same class as the child:

```
abstract class MyAbstractClass {
    public static function fromID($id) : MyAbstractClass { // This is on purpose. The child class is considered an instance of the parent class so it's fine
        return new static();
    }
}

class MyChildClass extends MyAbstractClass {
    public function specificFunctionToThisClass(){
         echo get_class($this);
    }
}

$item = (new MyChildClass())->fromID(3);
$item->specificFunctionToThisClass();   // prints 'MyChildClass'
```